# How to make a react + d3 stacked bar chart grouped?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using react + d3 to create a stacked and grouped bar chart, I made it stacked but couldn't find how to make it grouped also?

I want something like this image

[image]

data looks like:

```js
    const data = [
      {
        name: "Brand 1",
        Affiliate: 10,
        Social: 20,
        Media: 30
      },
      {
        name: "Brand 2",
        Affiliate: 20,
        Social: 40,
        Media: 60
      },
      {
        name: "Brand 3",
        Affiliate: 30,
        Social: 45,
        Media: 80
      },
      {
        name: "Brand 4",
        Affiliate: 40,
        Social: 60,
        Media: 100
      },
      {
        name: "Brand 5",
        Affiliate: 50,
        Social: 80,
        Media: 120
      }
    ];
```

and the part that generate stack looks like:

```js
    const stackGenerator = stack().keys(keys);
    const layers = stackGenerator(data);
```

you can check the full code and demo in [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-cookies-vf5xe?file=/src/BarGraph.js)

any help to make it stacked + grouped will be appreciated

Comment: How do you want to group each data?

Comment: I want it to look similar like the image attached, is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean, how do you know that two or several bars will be grouped together? Will they always be grouped by two? Is there an attribute you want to group on?

Comment: they always be grouped by two and want to group based on name  attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/LyssenkoAlex/21df1ce37906bdb614bbf4159618699d), something like this should work: you can find the entire example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-feistel-pwgml).

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Brand 1",
    type: 1,
    Affiliate: 10,
    Social: 20,
    Media: 30
  },
  {
    name: "Brand 1",
    type: 2,
    Affiliate: 20,
    Social: 40,
    Media: 60
  },
  {
    name: "Brand 2",
    type: 1,
    Affiliate: 30,
    Social: 45,
    Media: 80
  },
  {
    name: "Brand 3",
    type: 1,
    Affiliate: 40,
    Social: 60,
    Media: 100
  },
  {
    name: "Brand 3",
    type: 2,
    Affiliate: 50,
    Social: 80,
    Media: 120
  }
];
```

Make two nested axes:

```js
    const x0Scale = scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((d) => d.name))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.46);
    const x1Scale = scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map((d) => d.type))
      .rangeRound([0, x0Scale.bandwidth()])
      .padding(0.12);
```

and make the width of the bar dependent on the width of the smallest axis:

```js
.attr("x", (sequence) => x0Scale(sequence.data.name)
                         + x1Scale(sequence.data.type))
.attr("width", x1Scale.bandwidth())
```

This yields the following picture:

[image: The resulting image]

The only downside is that the solution assumes that every group has the same members - otherwise it doesn't draw them, as you can see from the gap to the right of "Brand 2".